# UPDATE TypeError and Unable to set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined or null reference: i is undefine Asp.net Mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having this issue with datables in `Asp.net mvc`; I've done a number of research and nothing that I have tried work. I'm getting this error when I use firefox `TypeError: $(...).DataTable` is not a function and this error when I use microsoft edge: `Object doesn't support property or method 'DataTable'`. Guess they have the same meaning.

**Update**
After following the suggestions that were given I then encounter on this error: TypeError: i is undefined

**table**

```
<table id="data" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-lg-3 tablehead">Expense Account</th>
                <th class="col-lg-3 tablehead">Description</th>

                <th class="col-lg-3 tablehead">Item Number</th>
                <th class="col-sm-1 tablehead">Quantity</th>
                <th class="col-sm-1 tablehead">UOM</th>
                <th class="col-sm-1 tablehead">Cost</th>
                <th class="col-sm-1 tablehead">Extended Cost</th>


            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].postTrnx, new { @class = "checkGroup1" })</td>
                    <td class="label">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].requisitionNumber) </td>
                    <td class="label">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].transactionDate)</td>


                </tr>
                foreach (var item in Model[i].items)
                {

                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@item.expense_account.account_desc</td>
                        <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@item.description</td>
                        @*<td class="label">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].requisitionNumber) </td>*@
                        <td class="col-lg-3 tabledata">@item.itemNumber</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 tabledata">@item.quantity</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 tabledata">@item.selecteduomtext </td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 tabledata">@item.price</td>
                        <td class="col-sm-1 tabledata">@item.extended_cost</td>
                        @*<td class="label">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].transactionDate)</td>*@
                        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = @item.lineNum, name = Model[i].docNumber })</td>
                    </tr>

                }
                @*<tr> <td></td></tr>
                <tr> <td></td></tr>
                <tr> <td></td></tr>
                <tr> <td></td></tr>*@
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**.layout.cshtml**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - TWCL Issue Management System</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**view**

```
      @section Scripts { 
        <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#data').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're including jquery and jquery-ui several times... only do each one once.

Comment: I'm not seeing where I have included several times. where could i look

Comment: `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

Comment: so i should remove two of them

Comment: what is it that I should be doing because I remove these     
 
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jqu‌​ery.min.js"></script‌​> and was getting an object expected error

Comment: You only need *one* of each script. Remove enough so that you only have one of each script remaining.

Comment: Aside from referencing JQuery more than once, I'd suggest you put this line: @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) in at the base of your view and not the head. It sounds like DataTable js file is not yet loaded when you call it

Comment: Yeah I have remove two of the scripts however now I'm I'm getting this error from the plugin TypeError: i is undefined

Comment: it is at the base @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

Comment: well you're missing a closing </head> tag then

Comment: ok i'm still get the error about undefined i

Answer (score 0):

You're using some seriously outdated stuff. I put up a jsfiddle here that is working (well, gets you past your issue). I would suspect that your script refs are not in the correct order or something.

```
<body>
    <table id="data">
    data table
    </table>
</body>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#data').DataTable();
} );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2s2Lq9mh/

Comment: my problem is within the plugin now

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
those are my script files; the issue is with the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Based on researches I found out that there should matching td  to th; that is what I used to solve the issue and now datatables is working fine.